# retrieving pointer field in C structure correctly

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I am writing a C program. I have a data structure called `MyStruct` that contains a character pointer and also an integer field. I have an array of `MyStruct` called `myArray`. What I need is to simply initialize this array by `MyStructure` structs by `initiateParams()` function and then read the values of myArray and display them on screen by `displayParams()`.

The `initiateParams()` function just initializes integer and `char*` fields of variables of class `MyStruct` by incrementing integers. After initialization, when I want to retrieve values by `displayParams()` the value of integer field (`intigerData`)  is retreived correctly; but the value of pointer field (`characterSet`) displayed incorrectly; maybe the value of last `char*` value assigned to the last structure. How can I retrieve pointer values correctly? Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include"structHeader.h"
#include <stdint.h>

void initiateParams();
void displayParams();
char* itoa(int value, char* result, int base);


typedef struct _MyStruct
{
    char* characterSet;
    uint16_t intigerData;
    uint16_t * intigerDataPtr;

} MyStruct;

const uint16_t bufferSize  =  400;
MyStruct myArray[400];
int main ()

{    initiateParams();
    displayParams();

    printf("ended");
    return 0;
}

void initiateParams(){
    uint16_t i;
    for(i = 0 ; i < 4*bufferSize ; i++){
        uint16_t k = i % bufferSize;
        MyStruct myStruct;
        myStruct.intigerData = i;
        char c;
        char* c2 = itoa(i , &c , 10);
        c = *c2;

        myStruct.characterSet = &c;
        myStruct.intigerDataPtr = & i;

        //printf("%s\r\n" , &dig);
        myArray[k] = myStruct;
    }
}

void displayParams(){
    uint16_t i;
    for(i = 0 ; i < bufferSize ; i++){
        MyStruct api = myArray[i]; 
        printf("retrieved integer value: %d , character pointer value: %s\r\n" 
                , api.intigerData , api.characterSet);
        printf("%s\r\n" , api.characterSet);
    }
}

/**
* C++ version 0.4 char* style "itoa":
* Written by Lukás Chmela
* Released under GPLv3.
*/
char* itoa(int value, char* result, int base) {
    // check that the base if valid
    if (base < 2 || base > 36) { *result = '\0'; return result; }

    char* ptr = result, *ptr1 = result, tmp_char;
    int tmp_value;

    do {
        tmp_value = value;
        value /= base;
        *ptr++ = "zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba9876543210123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" 
                [35 + (tmp_value - value * base)];
    } while ( value );

    // Apply negative sign
    if (tmp_value < 0) *ptr++ = '-';
    *ptr-- = '\0';
    while(ptr1 < ptr) {
            tmp_char = *ptr;
            *ptr--= *ptr1;
            *ptr1++ = tmp_char;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
 myStruct.characterSet = &c;
```

only stores a pointer to the temporary variable 'c' which is allocated on the stack.

You should at least store the value of 'c2' variable (without '*') in the characterSet field.

Also you are not allocating the buffer, passing &c to itoa is erroneous.

You should (for each character)  allocate the buffer:

```
    char* buf = malloc(10);
    myStruct.characterSet = itoa(i , buf , 10);
```

and deallocate the structure when you're done (after displayParams).

The code should be

```
void initiateParams(){
    uint16_t i;
    for(i = 0 ; i < 4*bufferSize ; i++){
        uint16_t k = i % bufferSize;
        MyStruct myStruct;
        myStruct.intigerData = i;

        char* buf = malloc(10);
        myStruct.characterSet = itoa(i , buf , 10);
        myStruct.intigerDataPtr = & i;

        myArray[k] = myStruct;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, because I used to programming in Java, I didn't noticed that the memory space of local variables will be recovered after function call ended; Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`characterData` print fail because it points to an address (variable `c`) that exists only into the scope of `initiateParams()`

i think you need to make a `malloc`, assign the value to the newly allocated byte and assign the address of the latter to the `characterSet` pointer .

Or more easily convert `characterSet` from `pointer to char` to simple `char` and init it by value.